# Continuous Integration Builds - Versioning

Tags: maven-2, continuous-integration, maven, versioning

I had a question regarding the use of version numbers, RELEASE versions and continuous integration.

So far in our builds we have been using RELEASE as the version for all the components in every build.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>mydependency</artifactId>
    <version>RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

This has the advantage that we always use the most up to date release of every dependency but has the major drawback that our builds are not reproducible as you don't know what dependencies were supposed to be used at a point in the past (as the versions says RELEASE not 1.3.2 for example).

If we switch to using fixed release numbers, we get reproducible builds, but don't we lose the advantage of Continuous Integration telling us what has now broken? Isn't this the point of Continuous Integration?

What is the standard way of doing this?

Regards,
D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, plan to stop using `RELEASE`.  It is [no longer supported](https://cwiki.apache.org/MAVEN/maven-3x-compatibility-notes.html#Maven3.xCompatibilityNotes-PluginMetaversionResolution) in Maven 3 for plugin versions; it appears that references to it have been removed from the online books about Maven and I would expect it to be deprecated for dependency versions eventually if it isn't already (I can't find authoritative information one way or the other).  Review/ask the users mailing list for confirmation if you are unsure about this.  You've already learned the hard way about build reproducibility.

Second, I agree with the answer that you will generally want to define fixed versions for your projects' dependencies, unless you are making changes to multiple projects at once, in which case you want a SNAPSHOT dependency version.  But this should only be until they are ready to be released.  At that point, you should release the lowest-level one, switch the dependency specifiers to the new fixed version in the other projects, and repeat for each project until done.  You should only release a new version of a project if all of the dependencies are fixed versions.  The [release plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/) can help with this.

Third, it can still be very useful or interesting to know if the current "tip" of multiple projects work together, even if they are on independent release schedules!  Backward/forward compatibility planning, right?  With more projects this becomes more important.  I think this is the "continuous integration" you are talking about (although these days CI usually refers to continuously building and testing the changes from multiple developers working on a single branch).

In this case you should create a top-level aggregator project that defines all related projects as modules.  You can do this in a workspace without committing changes to version control, or you can create an integration-specific branch for each project that tracks the mainline changes.  In either case, you will then want to use the [versions](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html):use-latest-versions goal to automate the updates to the POMs, or use [version ranges](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-project-dependencies.html#pom-relationships-sect-version-ranges) to let maven choose similarly to how you currently use 'RELEASE' (although I prefer having the version be as explicit as possible).

(Strictly speaking, you don't need the top-level aggregator, but otherwise you are having to do this with every project independently, when really you are interested in how they work together.)

Comment: Hopefully it goes without saying that you don't really care about reproducibility for the "tip of everything" builds, since it doesn't actually represent any current project configuration.  It's just an early warning system

Comment: +1 for mention of the versions plugin to make updating pom files easier.

Answer (score 2):

> If we switch to using fixed release
>   numbers, we get reproducible builds,
>   but don't we lose the advantage of
>   Continuous Integration telling us what
>   has now broken? Isn't this the point
>   of Continuous Integration?

No, I disagree. Every referenced project should have it's own CI build, and that should report what's broken.

If your CI project is project a and has a dependency to project b, the build a is supposed to test the validity of project a, not b. So the only thing interesting to Build a is that Project a works together with the specified version of Project b. (What the most current version of Project b does is irrelevant)

Comment: +1 even though: perhaps what the most current version of b does is "irrelevant", but that doesn't mean it's not useful to know if it introduces breaking changes or not.

Comment: @Zac true, but that would require a dedicated build that tests current versions of all projects wired together somehow.

Comment: agreed, that's exactly what I proposed doing if he is interested.  I agree fully with your approach for each project, although sometimes the project boundaries are not clear for teams starting from the "always use latest of everything" approach like the OP

Answer (score 2):

There are several conceivable solutions to your problem, the most common of which are:

1) You could combine several projects together, if they all must build and form a dependency tree anyway, into a coherent module set.  This uses the maven

```
<modules>
    <module>submodule-A</module>
    <module>submodule-B</module>
</modules>
```

format, which is concise, and it is helpful when grouping projects that should all be versioned together as a group.  You then just need a script that updates the version numbers of all the child pom.xml files to the correct revision whenever you do a release (or, my much less preferred option, use the maven-release-plugin).  That way, every part of the project moves and is versioned together as a whole; you can then start adding real revision numbers (i.e. 1.3.2).

2) If you can't collate common subprojects into a coherent solution with modules, the next best option is the use of SNAPSHOTS.  By setting the version in dependency project to something like:

```
<project>
    ...
    <artifactId>dependency-A</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <version>1.3.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    ...
</project>
```

you gain the ability to move in separate code bases at once.  Your primary project can either track the changes in the library by having a direct dependency on the snapshot:

```
<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <artifactId>dependency-A</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.company</groupId>
        <version>1.3.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>
```

or you can depend on an older version to continue the current development cycle (i.e. using 1.3.1), and then updating the dependency once the 1.3.2 version has been released.

This is option is slightly more complicated when tracking multiple independent projects, but it does retain the clarity of what depends on what version, explicitly in the source.  That is the downside compared to versioning modules together.  On the other hand, most CI systems (including Hudson) have a check box at the end of the configuration section for a job that asks "Build dependent projects?" (or something like that).  When checked and running as a maven build, whenever your SNAPSHOT dependency-A does a rebuild, Hudson can automatically kick off a build of any project that depends on dependency-A.  That can be quite convenient when you have a common, constantly updated dependency.